# how does the ant use in groovy

Tags: groovy, ant, pom.xml

this is a groovy script file MavenInit.groovy, execute in a pom.xml as follow, the var 'SCRIPTS_GROOVY' is defined in another pom.xml,what confuse me is I can not find where the "DIR_TARGET" definition, and how can use ant direct without `ant = new AntBuilder()`

```
SCRIPTS_GROOVY=project.properties['SCRIPTS_GROOVY']
ant.pathconvert(targetos:"unix", property:"DIR_TARGET") {
  path(location:project.build.directory)
}
DIR_TARGET=ant.project.properties['DIR_TARGET']
project.properties.setProperty('DIR_TARGET', "${DIR_TARGET}")
project.properties.setProperty('DIR_LOGS', "${DIR_TARGET}/logs")
ant.mkdir(dir:"${DIR_TARGET}/logs")
```

the pom.xml  excute the MavenInit.groovy as follow

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>set-maven-property</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scripts>
            <script>file:///${SCRIPTS_GROOVY}/MavenInit.groovy</script>
          </scripts>
       </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>Windows-package</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scripts>
            <script>file:///${SCRIPTS_GROOVY}/PackageWindows.groovy</script>
          </scripts>
       </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

how can I find the 'DIR_TARGET' initial defined and change the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMavenplus plugin [set an ant property](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/blob/1a9fedf489bd614a08329d0b39211598877765a9/src/main/java/org/codehaus/gmavenplus/mojo/AbstractToolsMojo.java#L108-L111) into its script

```
 if (!properties.containsKey("ant")) {
            try {
                Object antBuilder = invokeConstructor(findConstructor(classWrangler.getClass("groovy.util.AntBuilder")));
                properties.put("ant", antBuilder);
            }
```

Also there are other properties like `project`, `log`, etc.

---

About `DIR_TARGET`, I think it is the value of `project.build.directory` with path separator normalized as unix like, from `path(location: project.build.directory)`.

(I am not an ant expert, but I test on my computer and these two have same value.
Just adding the log lines to see

```
log.info( project.build.directory)
DIR_TARGET = ant.project.properties['DIR_TARGET']
log.info(DIR_TARGET)
```

---

I searched the ant doc and find an example from https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html, which verifies my guess.

```
  <pathconvert property="prop" dirsep="|">
      <map from="${basedir}/abc/" to=''/>
      <path location="abc/def/ghi"/>
    </pathconvert>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, and could you please guess where the ${DIR_TARGET} may initial defined? I use local global search, but can not find where the ${DIR_TARGET} defined